# live reloading marker without refreshing Map

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I have a streetview container on the right and the street view marker on the map on left, the marker is the Marker component inside Map and uses the streetview's current position. It moves as you move through the street view. My only problem is the whole map is refreshing, how to i make the streetview marker smoothly move as you move through the streetview, without reloading the entire map?

What am i looking for? the approach?

[image]